# "No parameterless constructor" error instantiating Controller registered w/Windsor Container

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, castle-windsor

Using MVC and trying to use dependency injection for controllers, but when I try to call a method on a controller that takes a dependency, I get the "no parameterless constructor" error.  Here's my setup:

```
ProductRepository : IProductRepository


ProductService : IProductService {
     public ProductService(IProductRepository repository) {} }

ProductController {
     public ProductController(IProductService service) {} }
```

In Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        InitializeServiceLocator();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }


    protected virtual void InitializeServiceLocator()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(container));

        container.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
        ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo(container);
        foreach (var handler in container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object)))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",
               handler.ComponentModel.Service,
               handler.ComponentModel.Implementation));
        }

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
    }
```

ComponentRegistrar:

```
public static void AddComponentsTo(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    AddCustomRepositoriesTo(container);
    AddApplicationServicesTo(container);
}
```

When InitializeServiceLocator completes, I can see that all Controllers, Services and Repositories are registered.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know in Ninject you have to register the parameter types in the service locator. You might need to do something similar with Windsor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still like to know the problem, but I've worked around it by creating my own WindsorControllerFactory per this post (with modification to avoid any web.config action):  http://mvcsharp.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/setting-up-ioc-in-asp-net-mvc-using-castle-windsor/

The WindsorControllerFactory in the previous code was the MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorControllerFactory.  Anyone using MvcContrib version successfully?

Thanks.